# What gems do I have to use to let users sign in with their Twitter account if I don't want to create Users Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, twitter-oauth

Today, there are few authentication gems such as **Twitter**(https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter)

Supposing that I have **posts** table, which has a field named "username".
Then I want to insert the value of usernames of their twitter accounts to it.

How can I design the system structure? What gems do I have to use to realize this procedure below?

1. A person sign in with his twitter account ID "test_john".
2. After confirmed his sign in to Twitter, my system receive callback then now he has a permission to post to my web service. Let's suppose that he posted a comment "hello".
3. New comment record will be created, and these values will be inserted to each

   comments.username <= test_john
   comments.body <= hello

Can I do this without using Devise or OmniAuth or something like these authentication gems?
or Do I have to use them anyway if I'm doing this?

What gems do I need at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called Omniauth here is the link https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But I don't think I need to use OmniAuth because in my case the system doesn't have to have Users table.